# CSS select box disabled stlying not getting reset

Tags: css, select, windows-8, modern-ui

In my win8 app have 2 pages. Page1.html and page2.html . Page1 has reference to ui-light.css and then page1.css. Page2 has reference to ui-light.css and page2.css.

ui-light.css has a rule defined for disabled state of select boxes. on page1.css I have overridden the select disabled style in this way.

```
select:disabled{
   background-clip: padding-box 
   background-color: rgb(45, 44, 44) 
   border-bottom-color: rgba(128, 128, 128,1) 
   border-left-color: rgba(128, 128, 128,1) 
   border-right-color: rgba(128, 128, 128,1) 
   border-top-color: rgba(128, 128, 128,1) 
   color: rgba(128, 128, 128,1) 
}
```

This works fine. But when I navigate from page1 to page2, all the select boxes in page2 have the same style(style in page1.css). How do I make sure this does not happen? I want the select boxes in page2.css to continue to use the style in ui-light.css.

I tried defining the style based on id, using !important. Nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't make a separate stylesheet for each page.

Comment: keep styles in same css, just have different names for classes or different ids, dont create 2 css files

Comment: That is how the app is currently designed... one for each page and for various reasons I cannot change that now... any other ideas? does it stick because I am generically defining fo a select? I tried defining for an id but the style still sticks...

Answer (score 0):

Load css for specifc pages..dont mention the stylesheet `page1.css` in the headtag of  the `page2.html`

Comment: I have not mentioned page1.css in the headtag of page2,html. That is what puzzles me.. How does it stick....

Comment: is ur website hosted...so that i can have a look?